# Dialogflow fulfillment how to support multiple buttons with Facebook messenger

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

I'm building a chatbot application with dialogflow, facebook messenger and firebase functions.
I need to create a question with list of buttons(not quick replies) as response options, I checked this library https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
they have cards, suggestions but they don't have buttons.

any suggestions on how to implement this buttons options task, either library or code are welcome.

I tried the card object but it only support 1 button.

Comment: Have you tried to implement this support yourself yet?

Comment: You can create multiple buttons in Cards using dialogflow web UI. Just press enter after adding 1 button. Have a look at this video for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC9Y-AmcL6A